# Make vector of rows that match a condition in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have a dataframe 'likes' that looks like this:

```
uid       Likes

123       Harry Potter
123       Fitness
123       Muesli
123       Fanta
123       Nokia
321       Harry Potter
321       Muesli
455       Harry Potter
455       Muesli
699       Muesli
123       Belgium
```

Furthermore I have a bunch of strings, for example: `WhatLikes <- c("Harry Potter","Muesli")`

I want a vector of the uid's that 'like' Harry Potter OR Muesli. Take note that `WhatLikes` is much bigger than this example.

The solution should thus be a vector that contains `123`,`321`,`455`,`699`.

Help me out! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to get a logical index of elements in 'Likes' that are found in 'WhatLikes'.  Get the corresponding 'uid' from the dataset.  Apply `unique` to remove the duplicate 'uid's.

```
unique(df1$uid[df1$Likes %in% WhatLikes])
#[1] 123 321 455 699
```

Comment: That's a bingo! Thank akrun.